# C#, Implementing Radio buttons in a form to calculate Nest Egg

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have been working on a problem where I would like to make a simple calculation. I am quite new to C# but I am attempting to learn.

Basically, how much money would I have to have saved up given four different inputs: Income Desired, Tax Rate, Estimated Rate of Return, and Income Per Time Period.

I am using a set of radio buttons to select income per time period, basically income on a daily, weekly, monthly, annual amount.  So, the radio button chooses how income is listed as a value but I am unsure of how to get the variable from this section into the calculation section. I will provide a code snippet.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
   private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Local variables
        decimal income;
        // Get the income, tax rate and rate of return.
        income = decimal.Parse(incomeDesiredTextBox.Text);

        // Determine pay period
        if (true)
        {
            if (incomePerDayRadioButton.Checked)
            {
                decimal newIncome = income / 365;
                return;
            }
            else if (incomePerMonthRadioButton.Checked)
            {
                decimal newIncome = income / 24;
                return;
            }
            else if (incomePerWeekRadioButton.Checked)
            {
                decimal newIncome = income / 52;
                return;
            }
            else if (incomePerYearRadioButton.Checked)
            {
                decimal newIncome = income / 1;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Local variables
        decimal income;
        decimal newIncome;
        decimal taxRate;
        decimal rateOfReturn;

        // Get the income, tax rate and rate of return.
        income = decimal.Parse(incomeDesiredTextBox.Text);
        taxRate = decimal.Parse(totalTaxesTextBox.Text);
        rateOfReturn = decimal.Parse(rateOfReturnTextBox.Text);


        //change rate of return to decimal format
        var rateOfReturnPercentage = rateOfReturn / 100;

        // Calculate Nest Egg.
        decimal taxedIncome = newIncome * taxRate;



    }
```

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](https://gyazo.com/b52272b73c9915f2c612793bf62f87fd).

Comment: I have included a link to Gyazo of what the form looks like so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should create a separate method that calculates new income.

```
public decimal CalculateNewIncome()
{
        decimal income;
        // Get the income, tax rate and rate of return.
        income = decimal.Parse(incomeDesiredTextBox.Text);

        if (incomePerDayRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            return income / 365;
        }
        else if (incomePerMonthRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            return income / 24; // should be 30 ?
        }
        else if (incomePerWeekRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            return income / 52;
        }
        else if (incomePerYearRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            return income;
        }
}
```

and then you can do calculation as

```
private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Local variables
    decimal income;
    decimal newIncome = CalculateNewIncome();
    decimal taxRate;
    decimal rateOfReturn;

    // Get the income, tax rate and rate of return.
    income = decimal.Parse(incomeDesiredTextBox.Text);
    taxRate = decimal.Parse(totalTaxesTextBox.Text);
    rateOfReturn = decimal.Parse(rateOfReturnTextBox.Text);


    //change rate of return to decimal format
    var rateOfReturnPercentage = rateOfReturn / 100;

    // Calculate Nest Egg.
    decimal taxedIncome = newIncome * taxRate;

    // display it
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, this makes so much more sense than what I was trying to do. What resources would you recommend for me to get a better knowledge of this language?

Comment: @Crawlersout - keep working on it, its just a matter of little time, keep practicing.